# Dynamically assigning sub class dependent decorators

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, decorator

I have a class that has a basic method, and subclasses that have the same base functionality, but additional behaviour, which can be implemented with decorators.

```
class cls_with_basic_method:

      #if...exec("@decoratorA")
      #if...exec("@decoratorB")
      #...
      def basic_method(arg):
      #...
         return arg

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorA(class_with_basic_method):
      #...

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorB(class_with_basic_method):
      #...

#...
```

It seems the quickest solution would be if I were able to execute the particular decorator as the subclass method is called, but can't think of a way of expressing it in python. Can this easily be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorated function or method is usually a different object than the function or method it decorates [*]  -  so, you can just wrap the original class' method in an explict way. This is rather straightforawrd, and rather boring -  but it will work if you need to decorate just a few methods of the sub-classes:

```
class cls_with_basic_method:

      def basic_method(arg):
         #...
         return arg

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorA(class_with_basic_method):
      basic_method = decoratorA(cls_with_basic_method.basic_method)


class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorB(class_with_basic_method):
      basic_method = decoratorB(cls_with_basic_method.basic_method)
```

The only special thing done there is use the decorators with the syntax of regular function calls instead of usign the "@..." syntax - this way they can be used inside the expressions.

This method is further boring due to you have to hardcode the superclass name within the class body at each decoration, since you can't use `super` from the class body, just from inside methods.

[*] Although some decorators just add metadata to the callable object they decorate and return the object itself - this approach won't work for such decorators, as they will affect the method in the superclass as well.

Now, taking your problem further - what you want is just to wrap arbitrary methods on the superclass when they are called on the subclasses. That can be done more or less automatically if you override the class`__getattribute__` - you then could create a class hierarchy with an special "decorator" attribute that would be called for each method call - more or less like this:

```
class cls_with_basic_method:
    _auto_decorate = set(("basic_method", ...))

    _decorator = lambda x: x  # NOP decorator
    def basic_method(arg):
        #...
        return arg

    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        # shortcircuit non-method retrievelas as fast as possible:
        if  not attrname in __class__._auto_decorate not callable(attr):
            return attr
        return self.__class__._decorator(attr) 


class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorA(class_with_basic_method):
    _decorator = decoratorA

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorB(class_with_basic_method):
    _decorator = decoratorB
```

Of course, if you need different decorators for different methods, just change the code in `__getattribute__` accordingly - the easiest way would be to make the `_decorator` attribute be a dictionary instead of pointing to a simple function.

(on a side note: the `__class__` magic variable, when used inside a method,  is a Python 3 thing: it automatically contains a reference to the class it is defined in (in this case, `cls_with_basic_method`).

This approach will redecorate the method on each call - it is not as much overhead as it seems to be - Python's default method retrieval mechanism itself is similarly complicated - but if you prefer to decorate the methods at class creation instead, tehn you can use a similar mechanism in a metaclass instead of relying on `__getattribute__`.

```
from itertools import chain

class AutoDecorate(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        if "_decorator" not in dct:
            dct["_decorator"] = lambda x: x # NOP decorator
        all_bases = list(chain(base.__mro__ for base in bases)) 
        for base in all_bases:
            if not "_auto_decorate" in base.__dict__:
                continue
            for method_name in base.auto_decorate:
                if method_name not in dct:
                    dct[method_name] = dct["_decorator"](getattr(base, method_name))
        return super().__new__(name, bases, dct)

class cls_with_basic_method(metaclass=AutoDecorate):
    _auto_decorate = set(("basic_method", ...))

    def basic_method(arg):
        #...
        return arg

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorA(class_with_basic_method):
    _decorator = decoratorA

class cls_with_basic_method_and_decoratorB(class_with_basic_method):
    _decorator = decoratorB
```

This is actually simpler than it might look: Upon creating a new class on the hierarchy, it just searches all superclasses for those which have the `_auto_decorate` attribute - and then it fetches the methods in that list, and decorate them with the decorator in the `_decorator` attribute of the class being created.

From what you are asking, I'd say you are dealing with a project where you need an "[aspect oriented programing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)" approach. There are several Python libraries that can provide that functionality - maybe you should take a look at that. If you think so, search for modules that can provide appropriate Python aspect oriented capabilities and use those.